# Apply sub on a single field and assign the result to a new field

Tags: jq

I have a JSON with the path:

> .softwareInfo.requirementsString

The value of the field `requirementsString` contains a string, of which I need only a part of this. For this i use `sub` I want to assign the result to a new field. I've come up with something below, but not sure (notice the `??`) how to apply the sub function to only the `requirementsString` field. So this code obviously doesn't work. What is the correct syntax for this?

```
.minimalVersion = .softwareInfo.requirementsString ?? 
    sub("iOS(?<version>.*?) or"; "\(.version)"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding the problem right, wrapping the right hand expression in parenthesis and using regular piping should do what you ask for.

```
.minimalVersion = (.softwareInfo.requirementsString | 
    sub("iOS(?<version>.*?) or"; "\(.version)")))
```